# Trying to understand binary conversion script

Tags: python, binary, cryptography, ascii

I have the following python code, which converts a binary string into plain-text:

```
import bin ascii
n = int('01100001011000100110001101100100', 2)
binascii.unhexlify('%x' % n)
```

This code functions properly, but I don't understand what's going on here.

1. What is the purpose of the "2" at the end of the int declaration?
2. What is the purpose of the "'%x' % n" argument?

Comment: The first creates an integer out of string and the '2' marks the string as integer representation in base 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the purpose of the `2` at the end of the int declaration?

[According to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int), `int` can take a second argument: the base of the first argument.

> What is the purpose of the `'%x' % n` argument?

`%x` in a string [indicates that an item will be formatted to hexadecimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) with lowercase letters. `'%x' % n`. It is similar to the builtin `hex` function, except it doesn't have the leading `0x` in the string. An equivalent expression would be [`format(n, 'x')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format).

Comment: Note: It's only coincidence this works. If the `int` value hadn't happened to require an even number of hex characters to represent, `binascii.unhexlify` would have barfed (it won't try zero padding on either end). On Python 3, you could get faster, correct behavior even when the `int` formats as odd-length hex, without `binascii`, by replacing the `unhexlify` line with: `n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big')` (which directly converts from `int` to `bytes` without producing an intermediate `str` at all, avoiding reliance on the hex representation entirely)